# Finding range of function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}$$
Prove that for all positive real number $a$, $1<f(x)<2$

According  to me i think question is not correct.
as at $a= 16$, we have case when function reaches
infinite value in left of $-1/2$.

Comment: $-1/2$ is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: at a=16, left of -1/2 is in domain

Comment: @MichaelHoppe He is referring to $x \to -\frac12^-$

Comment: @maveric I think simply that the problem is referring to $x\ge 0$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1597171p9921856

Comment: @greedoid That's confirms we need $x> 0$ for the given problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it seems to be true for

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}$$

only for $x>0$, indeed

$$f'(x) = -\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(1+x)^3}}+\frac{a}{ax+8}\frac{1-\frac{ax}{ax+8}}{2\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}}<0$$

and $$f(0)=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}<2, \quad f(x)\to 1 \quad x\to \infty$$

Comment: you have reformulated  the question?

Comment: Yes indeed the previous didn’t work too. I’ analyzing further what that function can be. What conditions where given on x?

Comment: Is that really an answer? It doesn’t prove anything ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I'm working a little biton it! I've answered that he is right indeed and I've asked some more information since the original problem wasn't clear, not as posted by the asker but from the original source.